# How do I get rid of this Error:Column alias list has 1 entries but 't' has 4 columns available while creating a view on top of a view in AWS athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have created a "dummy" table to access records stored in parquet in S3 & I have created a "dummy_flattened" view on top of "dummy" table using this query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dummy_flattened AS 
select
  deviceid
, a.postid
, a.craterid
, a.posttype
, a.category
FROM dummy cross join UNNEST(postlist) as t(a)
```

example of a postlist row :

> [{category=[{id=1, name=Dance}], craterid=1, postid=1, posttype=a},
> {category=[{2, name=Dance}], craterid=2, postid=2, posttype=b}]

Now when I try to create a view on top of dummy_flattened view using the query

```
create or replace view test as select distinct deviceid from dummy_flattened limit 100
```

Athena is giving me the error :

```
Failed analyzing stored view 'logs.dummy_flattened': line
19:12: Column alias list has 1 entries but 't' has 4 columns available
```

but i can view the results with the same query mentioned above

```
select distinct deviceid from dummy_flattened limit 100
```

However when i don't include a.postid,a.craterid...while creating the dummy_flattened i can successfully create test view.
However I couldn't figure out how to create a view on top of flattened view that includes postid,craterid,postype..without running in to a error.

I have been trying multiple combinations for the past few hours with no luck.

```
A few of the combinations i tried while creating flattened view

1. select deviceid,t.* as (a) FROM dummy cross join UNNEST(postlist) as t
2. select deviceid,(t.a.*) as (c,d,e,f) FROM dummy cross join UNNEST(postlist) as t(a)
3. And the one i mentioned above at the beginning
```

I would like to know if i'm missing something or can we not create views on top of unnested records. I have been refferring to multiple documents and other similar questions in stack overflow but couldn't find anything. As a last resort i'm posting this

Comment: Having the same issue. JFYI, CTEs does not help either. I have tried casting array (`postlist` in your case) to a single-field record (`cast(… as row(a varchar))`) in a CTE and got a weird error: `Row type must have at least one parameter`. `UNNEST` support in Athena v3 looks broken. Thank you for reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNNEST` looks broken in Athena engine v3. Athena v3 is based on Trino which unpacks arrays of rows into individual fields (see @Guru Stron's answer below), but it looks not fully supported.

As a workaround, one may **switch to Athena engine v2** to run a `CREATE VIEW` query with `UNNEST`. Once created, you may switch back to Athena version v3: `SELECT` queries on the view, created in v2, work fine.

For convenience, you may introduce a new Athena workgroup with engine v2 for views creation but use Athena v3 workgroup for querying since v3 has optimization advantages.

Comment: Can you query the view using Athena v3 when successfully created it using Athena v2?

Comment: Ok, I may confirm it myself: switching back to v3 and running SELECT query on a view created with v2, works fine. Will update your answer.

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be no problem querying views created using Athena 2 even when I switch versions

Answer (score 2):

[Docs](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) mention that every column of the row in the array is expanded into separate a column:

> `UNNEST` can be used in combination with an `ARRAY` of `ROW` structures for expanding each field of the `ROW` into a corresponding column

So you need to specify corresponding number of columns:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dummy_flattened AS 
select
  deviceid
, postid
, craterid
, posttype
, category
FROM dummy,
UNNEST(postlist) as t(category, craterid, postid, posttype)
```

Comment: I have previously tried this and have tried it again after your suggestion. It is giving me this error : `Column alias list has 4 entries but 't' has 1 columns available`

Comment: @SakethNaidu It seems that you have a non-homogeneous data set. What is output of `select distinct typeof(postlist) from dummy` ?

Comment: @SakethNaidu also this one is not mentioned among your attempts.

Comment: this is the output for typeof(postlist) `array(row(category array(row(id varchar, name varchar)), craterid varchar, postid varchar, posttype varchar))`

Comment: @SakethNaidu was not able to repro. Though I'm testing directly via Trino, not Athena. Which engine version are you using?

Comment: the athena engine I'm using is version 3. And i really admire your efforts

Comment: @SakethNaidu TBH I'm out of ideas TBH. Athena engine v. 3 should be based on Trino and unnesting array of rows directly into columns works in Trino.

Comment: yeah even I'm not sure how to tackle this. Logically there should be no error in parsing to columns

Comment: The answer is very simple...i'm not sure why but this is working absolutely fine with athena version 2...

Comment: @SakethNaidu v.2 is based on Presto. v.3 should be based on Trino possibly in some combination with Presto.